# Swift - Encoding keys not being properly sent in HTTP POST

Tags: json, swift, post

I am working on a POST request in my app that will send various information about a photo to a server (Note: I do not own the server). In order to get a success response I need to send a JSON object with the following key and their related values for that photo.

```
{
    "description":"example",
    "media_url":"https://example.com",
    "attribute[request_type]":"Example",
    "service_code":"123456789",
    "lat":"0.0",
    "api_key":"987654321",
    "long":"0.0"
}
```

In this call every key name needs to match EXACTLY.

My **problem** lies with the attribute[request_type] key. For some reason it is not properly recognizing that key name when I send it through my app. I know this because it gives me the following response message

```
    [{"code":400,"description":"Attribute request_type required"}]
```

I know the key name it says there is different from the one in the JSON object but I have tested using Postman that attribute[request_type] is the proper naming convention.

I know the issue is not with the value I am passing in otherwise it would tell me Attribute request_type invalid.

When I print the JSON object all the fields are there.

Exact output from the console:

```
    {"description":"example","media_url":"https:\/\/example.com\/","attribute[request_type]":"example","service_code":"987654321","lat":"0.0","api_key":"123456789","long":"0.0"}
```

This is how I have my struct set up

```
struct RequestModel: Codable {
    var api_key: String
    var service_code: String
    var description: String
    var media_url: String
    var requestType: String
    var long: String
    var lat: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case requestType = "attribute[request_type]"

        case api_key
        case service_code
        case description
        case long
        case lat
        case media_url
    }

    init(api_key: String, service_code: String, lat: String, long: String, media_url: String, description: String, requestType: String) {
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.service_code = service_code
        self.description = description
        self.media_url = media_url
        self.long = long
        self.lat = lat
        self.requestType = requestType
    }
}
```

And this is the function itself

```
func send(lat: Double, long: Double, comment: String, photoURL: String) {
        let lattitude = String(lat)
        let longitute = String(long)
        let description = comment
        let mediaURL = photoURL

        //Prepping Data
        let sendReqeust = RequestModel(api_key: "123456789", service_code: "987654321", lat: lattitude, long: longitute, media_url: mediaURL, description: description, requestType: "example")

        guard let uploadData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(sendReqeust) else {
            return
        }
        print(String(data: uploadData, encoding: .utf8)!)

        //Configuring an Upload Request
        let url = URL(string: "http://example.com")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        //Creating and Starting an Upload Task
        let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: uploadData) { data, response, error in
            print("Response: \(response)")
            if let error = error {
                print ("error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                    print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)
                    print ("server error")
                    return
            }
            if let mimeType = response.mimeType,
                mimeType == "application/json",
                let data = data,
                let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print ("got data: \(dataString)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Did I not set up the coding key properly? Is there an issue with my encoding method?

Comment: Hey! It is not clear, does it work with `Postman` or not? If yes, could you please attach `cURL` snippet? We need to be sure that it is not a server side bug. In order to do that, we can use any `REST` client tool. How to get `cURL` snipper from `Postman` you can find here https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/

Comment: @AlexD. I can report it does work in postman, however I cannot give the cURL without exposing the api_key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with `Alamofire` token handling, and I solved with `String` concat.

Try this:

```swift
 request.addValue("{\"request_type\":\"Example\"}", forHTTPHeaderField: "attribute")
```

EDIT

If the info really needs to be passed into the request body, try parsing like this:

```
{
    "description":"example",
    "media_url":"https://example.com",
    "attribute": {
        "request_type":"Example"
    },
    "service_code":"123456789",
    "lat":"0.0",
    "api_key":"987654321",
    "long":"0.0"
}
```

SOLUTION

I followed the above advice so now the code looks like this

```
    // in the struct requestType now looks like this
    var attribute: [String: String]
    // in the init within the function looks like this
    let sendReqeust = RequestModel(api_key: "987654321", service_code: "123456789", lat: lattitude, long: longitute, media_url: mediaURL, description: description, attribute: ["request_type":"example"])
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly in the end, submitted an edit with the necessary code changes for everyone's future reference

Answer (score 0):

change requestType = "attribute[request_type]" to  requestType = "request_type"